# MATLAB: Adding Noise with Regard to Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR) or EbNo?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, snr, bpsk, baseband

A signal `x` takes values from an alphabet set.
My objective is to estimate the channel parameters `hest` using adaptive methods and then plot the graph of mean square error (MSE) between the estimated coefficients and the actual vs range of SNR values considered. These are the following questions :

- Plot of BER vs. signal to noise ratio -- When I want to plot the BER, and the signal takes values other than BPSK say QAM then also I will be estimating the channel coefficients for each snr by adding `snr` using `awgn()` using the same code. Then should the X axis be labelled as `EsNo` or `EbNo`? In a similar question asked here [Adding AWGN noise with a correct noise power to the signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/33849/adding-awgn-noise-with-a-correct-noise-power-to-the-signal)

the answer is to use `EbNo`. In a Matlab implementation https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39011-ber-comparison-of-m-ary-qam?focused=5251697&tab=function, using the `EbNo` range the noise signal of a particular snr is generated. But, the BER plot shown has `EbNo` on X axis. This is confusing since the `awgn()` function is using `snr` and not `EbNo`.

- Plot of error vs snr -- For each noise added, I will calculate the error between the estimates and the actual coefficient. The X axis would be the range of snr and Y Axis the error values. Would the X Axis be `snr` or `EbNo` or `EsNo` irrespective of the symbol set?

  In my case the data takes values in symbols and not bits. What should I use? Please help in clearing these concepts. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These stuffs $E_s/N_0, E_b/N_0 \textrm{ and SNR}$ are convertible.

\begin{align}
E_s/N_0 &= E_b/N_0 + 10\log_{10}(k) \\
E_s/N_0 &= 10\log_{10}(T_{sym}/T_{samp}) + \mathrm{SNR}
\end{align}

where $k$ is the number of information bits per symbol, $T_{sym}$ is the signal's symbol period and $T_{samp}$ is the signal's sampling period. More details can be found at [AWGN channel MATLAB](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/awgn-channel.html).

And by [description of `awgn()` function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html):

> `y = awgn(x,snr)` adds white Gaussian noise to the vector signal `x`. The
>   scalar `snr` specifies the signal-to-noise ratio per sample, in dB. If `x`
>   is complex, `awgn` adds complex noise.

In your case, no oversampling thus `awgn()` uses its `snr` parameter to generate $E_s/N_0 =$ `snr`.

You are free to plot your BER curves over $E_s/N_0$ or $E_b/N_0$ because they are equivalent. You just need to convert them back and forth via the modulation order $k$.

However $E_b/N_0$ is usually prefered because ([EbN0 wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eb/N0))

> $E_b/N_0$ directly indicates the power efficiency of the system without
>   regard to modulation type, error correction coding or signal bandwidth
>   (including any use of spread spectrum). This also avoids any confusion
>   as to which of several definitions of "bandwidth" to apply to the
>   signal.

Comment: In my case, the data takes in symbols. So the transmitted information is in symbols. My application is in gene information representation and compressed sensing, where I am not using any particular modulation type as per norm in signal processing and channel estimation. My `h` are basically the transformation matrix and the symbols are from the alphabet set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. SO, there is no use of spread spectrum. Only the observation noise is assumed to be zero mean Gaussian random variable with varaince 1.

Comment: Since, `EsNo` term has `Es` in it and my data takes in symbols and not a compound bit word. So I don't have anysampling period etc since the data is already digital.I am confused regarding the following (A) whether to use `snr` or `EsNo` in the graph of error vs snr. Based on your answer, it `EsNo = snr` so I guess is it okay for me to use `snr` and not `EsNo` or `EbNo` label in the graph of Error Rate  vs. `EsNo` where `EsNo = Snr` so in effect I am actually plotting Error Rate  vs. `EsNo` where error rate is the error between each value of the actual symbol and the estimated symbol.

Comment: The other graph  plots the `Error between actual transformation matrix and estimates` vs SNR. Is this correct? Can you please confirm this part? (B) Confused about the formula of SNR. Could you please provide the formula for SNR (not the ESNo or EbNo). Thank you for your help.

Comment: (A) for a given system, one snr corresponds to one EsN0 and vice versa thus you can plot whatever you want. If you want to understand what is snr parameter in the awgn() function, in your case, it is snr=EsN0.

Comment: (B) the SNR formula is derived from the discrete-time model that is quite complicated. I am not sure if you find it interesting for your application. However, read this lecture, chap 2, especially section 2.5 for the complete answer about SNR and discrete time AWGN model. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/readings-and-lecture-notes/MIT6_451S05_FullLecNotes.pdf

Comment: THank you for clarifying the points. One last doubt, can you please help? When I say that the estimation performance is evaluated at different signal-to-noise ratio, does this technically mean that I am evaluating the performance in presence of noise of `different intensity `or `different power`? But the power of the signal remains fixed for these snr range?Am I correct in saying that I am `adding a noise of snr some db` or generating a signal which acts as the noise of snr some db ?

Comment: @RiaGeorge AWGN model, as its name, is just a model. And the performance of this model depends on the **ratio** signal over noise SNR. Thus, you can think like this. Personally, I prefer thinking we vary signal power which is easier to control and the AWG noise power is fixed because AWG noise is a model of pertubations caused by Brownian motion of particles at receiver that is (relatively) constant (it depends on temperature). Nevertheless, because this is a model, you can do both ways.